# Calculate the Volume Under Irregular Surface

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, interpolation, volume

I have a set of non-parametric [data points](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSuqqSVwLtY0NGmsbOMZUx5pyPH0mihP5ScaCIc8D6HDZXwFQtJzoj32GQMFe9G-NDx0rkr1rHu3cMG/pubhtml) and i need to calculate the volume underneath them. What i do right now is first use linear interpolation to augment the points and then basically implement a discrete integral.
[image]
The points are all supposed to be placed within a cylinder with a radius of `radius` and so i remove every point outside that threshold.
The real volume is 5485 cubic meters, but my function returns 6380.
I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't `n_points` (number of interpolated points) change the output of the function? I tried a `(10,10)`, `(50,50)`, `(100,100)` grid and the result barely changes.
2. Why is there such a large error in the result? As i said, I'm basically just integrating and as far as I'm aware i haven't made any mistakes implementing the integral.

```
def calculate_volume2(x, y, z, radius, n_points):
    x_points = n_points
    y_points = n_points
    # creating sample points for integral
    X = np.linspace(-radius, radius, x_points)
    Y = np.linspace(-radius, radius, y_points)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

    # Interpolating object
    # l = list(zip(x, y))
    interp1 = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(
        list(zip(x, y)), z, rescale=True)

    # Interpolating sample point
    Z0 = interp1(X, Y)

    # Integral
    sum_of_z = 0
    num_of_valid_sample = 0
    interp_points = np.zeros((1, 3))
    for i in range(len(Z0)):
        for j in range(len(Z0[i])):
            # checking if sample point is in cylinder boundary and interpolating value is valid
            if (not isnan(Z0[i][j])) and sqrt((X[i][j]) ** 2 + (Y[i][j]) ** 2) <= radius:
                num_of_valid_sample = num_of_valid_sample + 1
                sum_of_z += Z0[i][j]
                point = np.array([X[i][j], Y[i][j], Z0[i][j]])
                point = point.reshape(1, 3)
                interp_points = np.concatenate((interp_points, point), axis=0)
    # calculating surface of each sample tile: surface of cylinder base / number of samples
    surface_of_each_sample = pi * (radius ** 2) / num_of_valid_sample

    volume = sum_of_z * surface_of_each_sample
    height_avg = volume / (pi * (radius ** 2))
    return volume, interp_points, height_avg, surface_of_each_sample
```

Edit: `radius` in this case is 11.82 meters.

Comment: Why would the volume change if you add interpolated points ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Shouldn't it? I could be wrong but i thought of Trapezoidal rule
and assumed adding more points should reduce the error.

Comment: Real points, maybe. Points that were created from others (especially by linear interpolation) add no information.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Would you suggest a different interpolant or just scrapping that part?

Comment: This surface is a cone, isn't it ,

Comment: @YvesDaoust This one is, but i have other data sets and i need to generalize a solution.

Comment: A lot of them are somewhat cone shaped though.

Comment: Do not use scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator for data on a grid, use RegularGridInterpolator instead.

Comment: @ev-br how come? i tried but it gives me an error.
scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(
        list(zip(x, y)), z, rescale=True)
ValueError: There are 1837 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions

Comment: LinearNDInterpolator uses triangulation via QHull. RGI on the other hand, directly uses the regular grid strufture

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131545/calculate-the-volume-under-irregular-surface?noredirect=1#comment132600131_75131545), `LinearNDInterpolator` is not the best tool for interpolating data on a regular grid, since it's using triangulation via  [the QHull library](http://www.qhull.org/), so it's made with scattered data in mind.

For data on a regular grid, prefer `RegularGridInterpolator(...., method="linear")`.

However, for computing the volume under a piecewise linear surface, you don't need any of these in fact. Given the data on a grid defined by `x`, `y` and `z` arrays, the integral of a bilinear interpolant --- essentially a 2D trapezoidal formula --- would be

```
   trpz = .25*(diff(x)[:, None]*diff(y)[None, :]
             * (z[:-1, :-1] + z[1:, :-1] + z[:-1, 1:] + z[1:, 1:])).sum()
```

The formula comes from [scipy tests](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/interpolate/tests/test_fitpack2.py), and I remember to have checked it at least once, but you might need to adapt it to your definitions (e.g. whether your `z` arrays are 1D or 2D etc).